# 100%Рабочий код не хочет работать (считывание текстового файла)

Tags: c++

И так есть код залитый сюда: http://ideone.com/VJDgHg

```
    #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class KURSA4
{
  private:
    struct worker
    {
        int worked_together;
        int psy_compatible;
    };
    int n;
    vector<vector<worker>> ptr;
    vector<string> name;


  public:
    void print_matrix()  //Ð¾ÑÐ»Ð°Ð´Ð¾ÑÐ½Ð°Ñ ÑÑÐ½ÐºÑÐ¸Ñ, Ð½Ðµ Ð·Ð°Ð±ÑÐ´Ñ ÑÐ´Ð°Ð»Ð¸ÑÑ,
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            cout << name[i];

            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                cout << ptr[i][j].worked_together;
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
    KURSA4()
    {
        FILE* file = stdin; //fopen("list.txt", "rt");
        fscanf(file, "%d", &n);
        while(fgetc(file) != '\n');

        ptr.resize(n);
        name.resize(n);
        //ptr = new worker*[n];
        //name = new string[n];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            ptr[i].resize(n);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            char temp[50];
            fscanf(file, "%[^,]", temp);
            name[i] = temp;

            for (int j = i + 1; j < n ; j++)
            {
                worker temp;
                fscanf(file, ",%d,%d", &temp.worked_together, &temp.psy_compatible);
                ptr[i][j] = temp;
                ptr[j][i] = temp;
            }
            while(fgetc(file) != '\n');
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
    KURSA4 a2;
    a2.print_matrix();
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Как можно увидеть на сайте компиляция успешна(причем человек который помог его сделать компилировал его и в VS15), считывание прошло успешно и был выведен его результат. Но при попытке запуска в студии (естественно после исправления fopen) выдает просто пустую черную зависшую консоль (как будто бы бесконечный цикл). Дальше - больше, на том же сайте, тот же код, с тем же stdin, с тем же режимом С++14 при попытке компиляции мною выдает превышение время компиляции.
В чем дело? Почему у одного человека он компилируется, у другого нет Что нужно исправить?

Comment: На локальной машине стоит AVAST?

Comment: нет, никаких антивирусов и в помине нет

Comment: Запустите под отладчиком и пройдитесь пошагово.

Comment: Есть у меня подозрение, что дело в вашем `list.txt`. У вас нет никакой защиты от ошибок и неверного формата. Посмотрите на свой файл, все ли в нем верно, заканчивается ли последняя строка переводом каретки. Если да - попробуйте или прости под отладчиком, или натыкать отладочных вызовов типа `printf("Line %d\n",__LINE__);` и посмотреть, после какой строчки программа умирает...

Comment: Да, нехватало переноса последней строки. Я угробил на поиск этого бага 1,5 дня, уже начал заново код писать.... Harry+100500 в карму вам

Answer (score 1):

```
char temp[50];
```

50 байтов не хвататет для имени.
Русские буквы занимают два байта, поэтому при к-ве символов больше 24 происходит переполнение и начинается UB.

http://ideone.com/enL3SD

Поэтому выделите больше памяти для буфера (если не жалко).

Comment: может я что-то неправильно делаю, но не помгло(